# Specifying complex conditions in regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex, html

The id attribute values in HTML 5 has the following rules

```
1.The string should contain nonwhitespace characters
2. It should contain at least one letter
```

How can i represent this in regular expression form.I reached in a regular expression which satisfies the first condition..

```
/(^|\s)\S+/ig
```

But  how can i indicate the second condition in to the above regular expression
...and I am new to regular expressions...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have got your restrictions wrong. The [HTML5 ID data type](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/datatypes.html#common.data.id-def) must:

- must be at least one character long
- must not contain any space characters

That's:

```
^\S+$
```

Done.

Note:

- Without any characters in your regex (`\S` is not a character), you don't have to make your regex case-insensitive (`/.../i` is superfluous).
- Since your regex is anchored (`^...$`) there can only ever be a single match. This means there is no need for the "global" modifier, so `/.../g` is superfluous as well.

Comment: But this definition says...http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#the-id-attribute

Comment: @JinuJD I've linked to the W3C spec. The WhatWG says the same thing, by the way. Not sure where you got your definition, it's in none of those sources. (I'm being strict here. *"should contain nonwhitespace characters"* is not at all the same as *"must not contain whitespace"* and *"should contain at least one letter"* is not at all the same as *"must contain one character"*.)

Comment: they say that The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree and "must contain at least one character". The value must not contain any space characters.

Comment: @JinuJD Yes. My answer says the same thing (your question does not, even though I think you *mean* the same thing). What's your point? We are not in disagreement. ;)

Comment: But  ^\S+$ means one or more Non whitespace characters between beginning  and of string...It does not check whether the character contains atleast one letter...So it may match '99' also...am i right?

Comment: @JinuJD Yes. It means "at least one, at most any number of non-whitespace characters, but nothing else". Yes, that means `"99"` would pass. But the spec does not say anything about "letters" anywhere. That's only your interpretation. It speaks of "characters" - and `"9"` is a character.

Comment: ok...i thought that ,it should contain atleast one letter...Thanks for the clarifications

Comment: @JinuJD Reading a spec requires diligence. Don't jump to conclusions so easily.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10751/discussion-between-jinu-j-d-and-tomalak)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to match on two expressions.

```
myString.match(/(^|\s)\S+/i) && myString.match(/[a-zA-Z]/)
```

Comment: The ID cannot contain _any_ white space, so the first regex can/should be simplified to `/^\S+/i`.

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL There is no need for the `i` modifier.

Comment: @JinuJD But it's also wrong with regard to the spec. Besides, `/(^|\s)\S+/i` does not make any sense whatsoever. It means *"A string that starts with a non-whitespace character OR contains a space somewhere and has a non-whitespace character after it."*, which is not only not very helpful, it also allows a space character in the ID, which it definitely should not.

Comment: Ya i know..i know..i just copied and pasted the code from my program which has some more requirements....Didn't check that

Comment: @JinuJD *"Pasting code from the internet into production code is like chewing gum found in the street."* — Mike Johnson. (Never use foreign code without fully understanding what it does.)

Comment: No the code is written by myself man..copied from my own program